# Wordpress Frontend Post Form - Image upload should not be mandatory

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, wordpress-theming

I finally managed to get a wordpress frontend form working, creating a custom post type post and filling various custom fields. But since I integrated the media upload, the form submit is only working when a file is attached. But the media upload should not be mandatory, it  should be optional. Any suggestions are welcome!

```
// Formular Verloren
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

$post_information = array(
'post_type' => 'verloren',
);

$postID = wp_insert_post( $post_information ); //here's the catch

    //Image Upload
    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
                         require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                         require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                         require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
                 }
                    if ($_FILES) {
                         foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                                 if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                                         return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                                 }
                                 $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $postID );
                         }
                 }
                 if ($attach_id > 0){
                         //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
                         update_post_meta($postID,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
                 }


    //Custom Field Updates 
    update_field('field_580a640d6e458', $_POST['brand'], $postID);
    update_field('field_580a644ddc37f', $_POST['modell'], $postID);
    update_field('field_580a60c14f201', $_POST['date'], $postID);
    update_field('field_580a6191738cd', $_POST['spot'], $postID);
    ...


    //Redirect to Page
    wp_redirect(get_permalink(100)); exit;
}
```

This is my submit button, if this is relevant:

```
<button id="submit"  class="btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Publish">Submit</button>
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="new_post" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Maybe not the nicest code, but it works for me:

```
// Formular Verloren
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

$post_information = array(
'post_type' => 'verloren',
);

$postID = wp_insert_post( $post_information ); //here's the catch

    //Field Updates Verloren Post
    update_field('field_580a640d6e458', $_POST['brand'], $postID);
    update_field('field_580b7f49ed5dc', $_POST['mail'], $postID);

    //require the needed files
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    //then loop over the files that were sent and store them using  media_handle_upload();
            if ($_FILES) {
                    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                                    wp_redirect(get_permalink(100)); exit;
                                    die();
                            }
                            $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $postID );
                    }
            }

    //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
        update_post_meta($postID,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        wp_redirect(get_permalink(100)); exit;
        die();
}
```